# ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 2

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-3.6, valueerror

I figured out both error ROC curve and running big datasets through multiprocessing. This process works fine but after 30 minutes, I suddenly get an error.

**Multiprocessing Code Changed:**

```
for i in range(0, len(values) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(values)):
            # print(values[i], " and ", values[j])
            positive = []
            positive.append(values[i])
            positive.append(values[j])
            print(positive)
            proc = multiprocessing.Process(args=(positive,)) 
            print(proc)
            positives.append(proc)
            proc.start()

        for proc in positives:
            proc.join()

positives = pd.DataFrame(positives, columns=["file_x", "file_y"])
```

**Trace back**

```
    ['1013_StephenHawking_67_m.jpg', '1023_StephenHawking_45_m.jpg']
<Process(Process-236167, initial)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1671, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    make_block(values=blocks[0], placement=slice(0, len(axes[0])))
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 2744, in make_block
    return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 2400, in __init__
    super().__init__(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 131, in __init__
    f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khawar/deepface/tests/Ensemble-Face-Recognition.py", line 53, in <module>
    positives = pd.DataFrame(positives, columns=["file_x", "file_y"])
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 523, in __init__
    mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 234, in init_ndarray
    return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1681, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    raise construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (236167, 1), indices imply (236167, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

### edited

once again, I want to **emphasis** that your question is about `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 2`.

`ValueError` occurred because your variable `positives` is storing the object of `multiporcessing.Process` instead of (str, str), which is problematic.

Since you are just pairing up strings, i would do the following instead:

```
from itertools import combinations

data = idendities # using your json data 

# list comprehensive, create pairwise combination 
positives = [ list(combinations(v, 2) for key, value in data.items() ]
 
# unset nested lists 
positives = [ pair for l in positives for pair in l ]
# len(positives) = 3300 

positives = pd.DataFrame(positives, columns=["file_x", "file_y"])
```

**Outputs**

```
# positives before doing pd.DataFrame 

[('1020_StephenHawking_65_m.jpg', '1004_StephenHawking_43_m.jpg'),
 ('1020_StephenHawking_65_m.jpg', '1017_StephenHawking_65_m.jpg'),
 ('1020_StephenHawking_65_m.jpg', '1014_StephenHawking_67_m.jpg'),
 ('1020_StephenHawking_65_m.jpg', '1006_StephenHawking_36_m.jpg'),
 ('1020_StephenHawking_65_m.jpg', '1000_StephenHawking_1_m.jpg'),
 ('1020_StephenHawking_65_m.jpg', '1018_StephenHawking_66_m.jpg'),
   ... ... ]

# positives after pd.DataFrame

                         file_x                        file_y
0  1020_StephenHawking_65_m.jpg  1004_StephenHawking_43_m.jpg
1  1020_StephenHawking_65_m.jpg  1017_StephenHawking_65_m.jpg
2  1020_StephenHawking_65_m.jpg  1014_StephenHawking_67_m.jpg
3  1020_StephenHawking_65_m.jpg  1006_StephenHawking_36_m.jpg
4  1020_StephenHawking_65_m.jpg   1000_StephenHawking_1_m.jpg
```

Moreover, the memory issues definitely do not come from this part of the code.

Comment: I have to applied multiprocessing, otherwise the system got freeze.

Comment: thought it might be better to use `with Pool() as p: result = p.map(func, values)`; it is clearer. @KhawarIslam

Comment: Is it possible to post your answer? So that i can understand it more in better way. I thing there is some image problem. Whats your opinion?

Comment: i am not sure because you are not going much context here; like what is your goal?  the issue is clearly came from the last line (which is what your program error message shows)

Comment: Based on you above answer. This line has not work  proc = multiprocessing.Process(args=(positive,)). Am i right? Actually i have 20000 images and i am generating pairs to compare each other and find the similarity between each other

Comment: Before applying multiprocessing, When i run script it became freezes after 1 minutes. Then i search on google and applied multiprocessing to used 8 CPU to solve memory problem. Now, i don  not know that the actual problem is in multiprocessing code or list problem. Please clear my confusion, I have also implemented your answer and currently it is running.

Comment: what do u mean by freezes, possible it is running but your datasets are just so large that it takes long time to run so you thought it freezes but it is actually running. you could use logging to keep tracking of the progress;

Comment: freezes mean completely hang and then process kill. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65526655/process-finished-with-exit-code-137-interrupted-by-signal-9-sigkill-retriev

Comment: an example of your json file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65419970/process-finished-with-exit-code-137-interrupted-by-signal-9-sigkill

Comment: Please check identities list

Comment: I have applied this one positive_pairs = list(combinations(values, 2)). Error remained same.

Comment: @KhawarIslam i updated the answer. and i would strongly advised that you review your code and rethink the approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226798/discussion-between-khawar-islam-and-abc).

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case of messed up indexing.

Try  dropping any potential duplicate indices with `.loc[df.index.drop_duplicates()]`:

```
positives = pd.DataFrame(positives, columns=["file_x", "file_y"]).loc[positives.index.drop_duplicates()]
```

Comment: What is df here?

Comment: @KhawarIslam Typo, sorry :)

Comment: positives = pd.DataFrame(positives, columns=["file_x", "file_y"]).loc[positives.index.drop_duplicates()]
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'drop_duplicates'